# Generating target subdirectory with makefile based on dependency wildcard

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use make as a static-site generator (similar to Jekyll). Where the source is in a folder, and running `make` to generate the output into a separate directory 'build'.

The source has the following structure:

```
src
├── about.md
├── css
│   └── style.css
├── index.md
└─── posts
    ├── 2019-07-30-a-blog-post.md
    ├── 2019-07-08-another-post.md
    └── 2019-08-01-something-else.md
```

And I'm trying to get an output like this:

```
build
├── 2019
│   ├── 07
│   │   ├── a-blog-post
│   │   │   └── index.html
│   │   ├── another-post
│   │   │   └── index.html
│   └── 08
│       └── something-else
│           └── index.html
├── about
│   └── index.html
├── css
│   └── style.min.css
└── index.html
```

**Here's my current makefile...**

```sh
define generateHTML
    mkdir -p $(dir $1)
    pandoc -f markdown -t html5 -o $1 $2 -s
endef

SRC = src
DST = build

MARKDOWNFILES := $(filter-out $(SRC)/index.md, $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.md))
HTMLTARGETS := $(MARKDOWNFILES:src/%.md=build/%/index.html)
BLOG_MARKDOWNFILES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/posts/*.md)

### [WARNING] Hacky section here ###
# Replace '-' with ' ' for all parts of file basename
FINDREPLACE = $(subst -, ,$(basename $(notdir $(mdf))))
# Get the first 3 words of the space-separated list (YYYY MM DD)
# & format as YYYY/MM/DD-
# & replace all '/' characters with '-'
FINDREPLACE1A = $(subst /,-,$(word 1, $(FINDREPLACE))/$(word 2, $(FINDREPLACE))/$(word 3,$(FINDREPLACE)))-
# Replace the full path string, with the above.
# Get the filename, minus 'YYYY-MM-DD-' prefix.
FINDREPLACE1B = $(subst $(FINDREPLACE1A),$e,$(basename $(notdir $(mdf))))
# Build the full string required for HTMLTARGET variable
# & format into 'build/YY/MM/<string>/index.html'
findReplace2 = build/$(word 1, $(FINDREPLACE))/$(word 2, $(FINDREPLACE))/$(FINDREPLACE1B)/index.html
BLOG_HTMLTARGETS := $(foreach mdf, $(BLOG_MARKDOWNFILES),$(findReplace2))

all: build/index.html $(HTMLTARGETS) $(BLOG_HTMLTARGETS)

# This generates the root index.html
build/index.html: src/index.md
    $(call generateHTML, $@, $<)

# This generates the about/index.html pages, etc.
build/%/index.html: src/%.md
    $(call generateHTML, $@, $<)

### [WARNING] Hacky section here ###
build/%/index.html: $(BLOG_MARKDOWNFILES)
    $(eval WORDLIST = $(filter-out build,$(subst /,$e ,$(subst -,$e ,$(@D)))))
    $(eval QUERY = $(SRC)/posts/$(word 1,$(WORDLIST))-$(word 2,$(WORDLIST))%$(word $(words $(WORDLIST)),$(WORDLIST)).md)
    $(eval FUZZY_FILE = $(filter $(QUERY),$(BLOG_MARKDOWNFILES)))
    $(call generateHTML, $@, $(FUZZY_FILE))

# Tidy-up
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -Rf $(DST)
```

I've managed to hack something together - using the builtin functions `subst` / `word` / `words` / `filter` to perform a find/replace and match - which does successfully generate the output I want, but it re-generates *all* the files each time *one* of them is updated, and it seems far from ideal.

Is there a straightforward way to manipulate the target/dependency string for a makefile, to do something like this?

```
src/posts/YYYY-MM-DD-post.md => build/YYYY/MM/post/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a mission for [`foreach-eval-call`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function):

```
SUBDIRS :=
POSTS   := $(notdir $(wildcard $(SRC)/posts/*.md)) 

.PHONY: all
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

define MY_rule
$1.split := $$(subst -, ,$1)
$1.year  := $$(word 1,$$($1.split))
$1.month := $$(word 2,$$($1.split))
$1.day   := $$(word 3,$$($1.split))
$1.name  := $$(patsubst $$($1.year)-$$($1.month)-$$($1.day)-%.md,%,$1)
$1.dir   := $$(DST)/$$($1.year)/$$($1.month)/$$($1.name)

$$($1.dir)/index.html: $$(SRC)/posts/$1 | $$($1.dir)
    $$(call generateHTML,$$<,$$@)

all: $$($1.dir)/index.html

SUBDIRS += $$($1.dir)
endef
$(foreach p,$(POSTS),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$(p))))

SUBDIRS := $(sort $(SUBDIRS))

$(SUBDIRS):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Demo:

```
$ make
mkdir -p build/2019/08/something-else
pandoc -f markdown -t html5 -o src/posts/2019-08-01-something-else.md build/2019/08/something-else/index.html -s
mkdir -p build/2019/07/another-post
pandoc -f markdown -t html5 -o src/posts/2019-07-08-another-post.md build/2019/07/another-post/index.html -s
mkdir -p build/2019/07/a-blog-post
pandoc -f markdown -t html5 -o src/posts/2019-07-30-a-blog-post.md build/2019/07/a-blog-post/index.html -s
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do it, but none that is particularly clean.

The first problem is to transform a source name into a target name, e.g.

```
src/posts/2019-07-08-another-post.md => build/2019/07/another-post/index.html
```

A clever masochist could do this with Make functions, but I'd probably just invoke sed:

```
SRC := src/posts/2019-07-08-another-post.md
TARG = $(shell echo $(SRC) | sed 's|src/posts/\(....\)-\(..\)-..-\(.*\)\.md|build/\1/\2/\3/index.html|')
```

Once we have `SRC` and `TARG`, writing a rule is easy. Having Make write the rules automatically is slightly harder, but we can do it with a template:

```
define template
SRC := $(1)
$$(TARG): $(1)
    @echo building $$@ from $$^
    $(call generateHTML, $$@, $$<)
endef

$(eval $(call template,$(SOME_SOURCE)))
```

Now all we have to do is iterate over the source files, creating a rule for each:

```
$(foreach MF,$(BLOG_MARKDOWNFILES),$(eval $(call template,$(MF))))
```